# Битрикс, не уходит почта на CentOS

Tags: битрикс, email

Машина с простым CentOS, сверху установлены httpd и, собственно, всё php окружение с mysql.

Проблема в том, что от цмски не уходит почта.

В логах касательно почты - пусто.

В чем может быть проблема? В какую сторону копать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: mail() работает?

Comment: еще по адресу site.ru/bitrix/admin/sql.php?lang=ru&del_query=Y
выполните запрос select * from b_event
отобразится такая таблица как на скрине http://prntscr.com/ewgb8p и там смотрите отправляет ли битрикс

Answer (score 0):

Поставь postfix и настрой через какую почту(учетку) будешь отправлять. На всякий проверить не закрыт ли 25 порт.